# Confused about this javascript pattern

Tags: javascript

Encounter following lines of code, but couldn't understand it.

What is this (/*...*/)(this); purpose in javascript? Does it have name for this pattern?

Code as below:

```
//Move.js
(function(exports){
  exports.Move = function(){

  };
})(this);
```

Comment: this in javascript doesnt mean the class or the object but the context. Any javascript function can be called anyway , and you can change the value of this dinamically. in that exemple , it is just creating a function , calling it right away and assigning the value of this to the export argument. so in a nutsheel it is function definition then function calling with this as a parameter.

Comment: @camus—that's a very confusing explanation. A function's *this* value is not really dynamic, it is set by how the function is called and can't be changed afterward.

Comment: if you read me well , i talked about the context of the function that is dynamic. this is indeed dynamic as it is not set to one value , but depends on how the function is called. The explanation is pretty clear. this doesnt refer to one context ,therefore it is dynamic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this pattern is an "[Immediately Invoked Function Expresssion](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)". in short, it's just a function that is executed immediately. the `this` on the end is a parameter to be sent to the inner function that will be accessed as `exports`

```
(function(exports){

    //that was "this" outside, is now "exports" in here

}(this));
```

in your example, we can assume that whatever `this` was, it's some object that has been added  a `Move` method to it.

some also call this pattern the "[Module Pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth)" in a sense that it creates a "contained environment" so that the stuff inside it is not visible to the due to a new function scope. in other words, whatever is inside sees the outside, but the outside can only see what the inside lets it see

Comment: That isn't an example of the module pattern, it is just an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE), which are used with the module pattern to return an object with properties, methods and access to "private" members through closures.

Comment: *i didn't say* that my code up there is an example of the module pattern. my code up there is just showing `this` becoming `exports` inside the function. I didn't include an example of module pattern since everyone has his/her own style of building it.

Comment: hmm..when i think about it. What's the different with the above code with var exports = function(){//bla}.

Comment: using `var exports` creates a local variable `exports` and it will not refer the `exports` (which is `this` outside) that you passed. [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/dDf3A/2/)

Answer (score 3):

That pattern simply makes `exports` assigned to `this` at the time of execution.

Assuming the global scope and a browser, `this` will point to the `window` object.

With those assumptions in mind, `window.Move` should contain the function assigned inside of that IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression).

If this function were called in a different context where `this` is *not* `window`, it will assign that method to whatever `this` was in the outer environment.

Comment: Probably better to say that in global code, *this* always references the global object. In some environments (e.g. browsers) there is also a *window* object which is essentially the same object (but may not be), so *this* in a global context references *window* too.

Answer (score 1):

This pattern is called "Module Pattern". There are various sub patterns and this one used Augmented Module pattern.

> First, we import the module, then we add properties, then we export
>   it. Here's an example, augmenting our MODULE from above:

For more read about this Module pattern check out http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth

For more reading about general Javascript patterns check out
http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

Comment: http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/ is a VERY good, detailed, and with numerous examples, absolutely a must read!